# How to see list of #TODO-s in Spyder?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I use '#TODO: xxx' format for marking todo-s in Spyder. Is there any way to see full list of TODO-s in a file, in Spyder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to the menu

`Source > Show todo list`

to get the full list of TODO's in your file.